# Redirecting to the same page after facebook login so that i can make posts accordingly

Tags: php, facebook, magento, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Submission of form should be done when on user login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395923/submission-of-form-should-be-done-when-on-user-login)

Following is my code in which I have been trying to make an script if my checkbox for posting on facebook is being checked then firstly the user will be checked either he is login to facebook or not but if he is not then he'll be redirecterd to facebook page, login to it and redirect back to the same page.
I am working on magento and when ever i check the checbox to post on facebook then it redirects me successfully to facebook and login me over there but its not redirecting me back successfully and giving an error of invalid form data 
Kindly let me know how can i modify the following code that'll help me in accomplishing the task i have been trying to do.

```
 function myfunction()
    {
    $myformData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('myform');
       $fbpost=$myformData['fbpost'];
$app_id = "APP_ID";
            $app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
            $facebook = new Facebook(array(
             'appId' => $app_id,
             'secret' => $app_secret,
             'cookie' => true,
             'fileUpload' => true,
            )); //making object for facebook connectivity

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user==0 && isset($fbpost)) // checking if user is login to facebook or not
{
header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'photo_upload,publish_stream,user_photos,manage_pages'))}"); //redirecting to facebook

}
else
{


          //  $con = $this->_getConnection();
    //        Mage::helper('Octopus/')
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore();$userId = $store->getName();
              $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection(core_write);

             $myformData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('myform');
           $fbpost=$myformData['fbpost'];
            if(isset($fbpost))
            {
                echo Mage::helper('function')->test();


            }
                $couponId = $myformData['coupon_id'];
                $coupontype=$myformData['coupon_type'];
                 $select = $db -> select();
            $select -> from('ops_mobile_coupons')
            -> where('id =?',$couponId);

             $data = $db -> fetchRow($select);
            $select = $db -> select() -> from('ops_image_type_coupon_details')->where('coupon_id = ?',$data['id']);
                $x = $db->fetchRow($select);

                $image=$x['image_path'];

    //        -> andWhere('client_id = ?', $userId);

               if(isset($fbpost) and $coupontype == 'image')
            {
    //Image Facebook Starts                 

                $app_id = "APP_ID";
                $app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
                $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                 'appId' => $app_id,
                 'secret' => $app_secret,
                 'cookie' => true,
                 'fileUpload' => true,
                ));



    $accounts_list = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');



                $accounts_list = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');

                //to get the page access token to post as a page
                foreach($accounts_list['data'] as $account){
                      if($account['id'] == 'me'){      // my page id =123456789
                        $access_token = $account['access_token'];
                        //echo "<p>Page Access Token: $access_token</p>";
                        }
                    }
                $attachment = array('message' => 'image coupon',
                                'access_token'  => $access_token,
                                'link' => 'http://operture.com/jeegesh/index.php/octopus/adminhtml_coupon/postpart2/key/34f1bf523a35bc8c9213d669097f8e50/',

                                'source' => $image,

                                );
                $status = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment);   // my page id =123456789
                //var_dump($status);
        }
    //Image Facebook Ends }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the the `redirect_uri` you're using match the URL you've configured for your app in the app settings? if it doesn't, the app auth will fail with error 191 (non-admins will not see the specific reason)